# R image export resolution issue

Tags: r, rstudio

I am generating a correlation matrix then zooming into the image and clicking save for a very detailed correlation matrix, but the resolution turns out terrible. Is there any way to save this image with a better resolution?

Note: I tried saving the matrix using some of the examples [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/high-resolution-figures-in-r/) but nothing saved correctly, possibly due to how I am creating the visualization.

```
eCor<-cor(eTotals,y=NULL,use="pairwise.complete.obs")
mixedCor<-corrplot.mixed(eCor)
jpeg("Plot3.jpeg", width = 4, height = 4, units = 'in', res = 300)
plot(mixedCor, y=NULL) # Make plot
dev.off()
```

The output is a single